# Is there a way to ensure that my ImageDataGenerator's preprocessing_function works properly?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, opencv, keras

My preprocessing_function detects and blurs faces. How to plot images from ImageDataGenerator to make sure that it works? The code is below:

```
haarcascades_loc = "libopencv-4.0.1-hbb9e17c_0/Library/etc/haarcascades/haarcascade_profileface.xml"
pface = cv2.CascadeClassifier(haarcascades_loc)
def BlurFaces(image):
    gray_fr = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray_fr = np.array(gray_fr, dtype='uint8')
    faces = pface.detectMultiScale(gray_fr, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces: 
        blur_face = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        blur_face = cv2.GaussianBlur(blur_face,(23, 23), 30)
        image[y:y+blur_face.shape[0], x:x+blur_face.shape[1]] = blur_face
    return image
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=0.20, preprocessing_function=BlurFaces)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=r"State Farm Distracted Driver Detection\imgs\train",
    target_size=(224, 224),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=128, #32, 64, 128, 256 or 512
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42,
    subset="training",
)

valid_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=r"State Farm Distracted Driver Detection\imgs\train",
    target_size=(224, 224),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=128,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42,
    subset="validation",
)
```

**Edit:** I used this block of code to check the images

```
images, labels=next(train_generator)
print(batch[0].shape) 
images=batch[0][0]  
print (images.shape)
plt.imshow(image.astype(np.uint8))
```

Comment: You tried to plot some images to see if it is working or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you need to provide some images to the generator using .flow or.flow_from_directory or .flow_from_dataframe.  For example
train_gen=datagen.flow_from_directory( etc) Then try

```
images, labels=next(train_gen)
```

images will be of the shape (batch_size, height, width, channels)
plot the images to see if you get what you expect. Be aware the preprocessing_function must return an image of the SAME dimensions as you
specified in target_size and must have the same number of channels as specified
by color_mode.